# ASP.NET Relative Path To File in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I want to specify a path to a file in my application in the Web.Config file, then call that path in a controller.
From what I've found online, I'm most of the way there.

**Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="filePath" value= "~/App_Data/Physicians.xml" />
</appSettings>
```

**Controller**

```
//Path of the document       
string xmlData = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"].ToString();
```

However, this is pointing to the wrong location.

[image]

How can I point this to the file I have stored in the App_Data folder, starting from the root of my application?

Comment: I know |DataDirectory| works in the connection string. Not sure in AppSettings.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `Server.MapPath`.

Or alternatively, store only the relative path in the configuration file, then use:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="filePath" value= "App_Data/Physicians.xml" />
</appSettings>

string relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"];
string combinedPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)
```

The latter technique will work in non-web applications, so is arguably better.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this a little more?
Are you saying that I leave the Web.Config portion alone?  Can you write out how you would make this call in the controller?  I don't see how I would use your Path.Combine example with what I have, or if I'm supposed to replace all of that.

Comment: relativePath would be the part which you store in your Web.Config. You would remove the tilda from your path and then go something like var relativePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filePath"].ToString() and then use Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, relativePath)